# How to write Treeview info for your application in tkinter (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am looking for a way to write information for my treeview in `tkinter`. I wrote this by using the set method but my sentences disappear when I write on the next line. I want my information for the teeeview to display when I move to the next line.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


root =Tk()


tree = ttk.Treeview(root)
tree.insert("","0","item1",text="LANGUAGE")
tree.insert("","1","item2",text="GUI")


tree.insert("item1","1",text="Version")
tree.insert("item2","end",text="Tkinter")

tree.config(columns=("NOTE"))
tree.column("NOTE",width=300)
tree.heading("NOTE",text="Info")


tree.set("item1","NOTE","Am using python version 3.6.1 \n on windows machine  
")
tree.set("item2","NOTE","This an example Tkinter Treeview in Python, which 
is from \nttk class make sure import ttk\n also from tkinter import *")

tree.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Are there any methods in treeview I can use to display this, because I want to write a lot of information for the treeview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to increase the height of the rows so that all your text will be visible. The height of the rows can only be modified by using a style:

```
style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('my.Treeview', rowheight=50)

tree.configure(style='my.Treeview')
```

As far as I know, it is not possible to adjust the height of a single row.

Comment: Really works .so if i want the sentence for only  the treeview have selected to display, how Will i  achieve this. Example if i select treeview language,i want the sentences for only  the  treeview under column to display. Then when i select treeview version only the sentences for the treeview will display without displaying sentence for other treeviews until i select it to display

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want to do. Do you have several treeviews or do you want to see the full content of the selected item only? I don't understand what you mean when you are talking about columns. I suggest you either to edit this question with a mcve about that or to ask a new question about it.

Comment: Exactly, I have several treeview but i want to see the content of selected item only when i select it. To display only the content of  selected treeview.